# How do I stop a git error message after removing ScaleFT?

Tags: git

After removing the ScaleFT application from my Mac I now get a git error message every time I pull:

```
% git pull
zsh:1: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/sft
```

Git still works, but how can I remove the message?

Answer (score 2):

In your `~/.ssh/config`, remove the entire section starting with `Match exec "/usr/local/bin/sft resolve -q  %h"`